# Visual Studio 2008 extensions for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, v1.3 – Mar 2009 CTP

Tags: sharepoint

Good day,

Kindly I'm looking for the VSeWSSv13 x64 as I couldn't find a source for the executable file and it is not exist in Microsoft as I need it for old SharePoint solution.

I couldn't find a source for the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, unfortunately, there is no source or method to install `VSeWSSv13`.Since it is too old, I recommend that you use the new version of SharePoint instead of the old version of SharePoint. Thanks for your understanding.